# Distinct and separate <ui-view>s for different states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My application has a bunch of states defined using `ui-router`

`home.js`

```
//.... 
.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<home></home>',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .state('single',{
        url: '/post/:slug',
        params: {id: undefined},
        template: '<single></single>',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })
})
// ... some other stuff
```

At the same time, I have my CMS routes defined in `admin.js` like so:

```
import createTemplate from './create/create.post.html';
import adminLayout from './admin.layout.html';

.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/admin',
            template: adminLayout
        })

        .state('admin.create', {
            url: '/create',
            template: createTemplate,
            access: {restricted: true}
        })
        .state('admin.posts', {
            url: '/posts',
            template: '<allposts></allposts>',
            access: {restricted: true}
        })
        .state('admin.edit', {
            url: '/edit/:id',
            template: '<editpost></editpost>',
            access: {restricted: true}
        });
})
```

I have 2 *master* layouts-one for the the non-CMS routes, and the other for the CMS routes. The reason for keeping them distinct is because they have different UI elements; different enough to justify keeping them in different layouts.

`app.html`

```
<div class="app">
<div class="container">
    <div class="body row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <navbar menu-items="ac.navItems" orientation="vertical" logo="true"></navbar>
        </div>

        <div ui-view></div>

        <footer class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <span translate="{{'footer.copyright_symbol.fragment'}}"></span>
            {{'footer.copyright_years.fragment' | translate}} {{'colophon.author_name.fragment' | translate}}
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

`admin.layout.html`

```
<div>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I navigate to `/admin/create` or any of the `admin` routes, I see the layout for `app.html` *as well as* the layout for `admin.layout.html` together.

How do I configure the `ui-view`s such that I can have *distinct* layouts for the non-CMS routes and the CMS ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a specific name for each different views, see this :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views